# What does $\cup _f$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, notation, cw-complexes

I saw the symbol $\cup _f$ in the definition of "Cell attachment" in an algebraic topology notes, it says:

[image]

What does the symbol $\cup _f$ mean?

Comment: This is a definition of the symbol $\cup_f$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is defining the symbol, and the right hand side of the equation is what it means. You might pronounce it as "$X$  glued to D^n along $f$."

(Your photo doesn't include the definition of $\sim$ but that is also very important.)

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, what does the $\sqcup$ symbol mean? The notes doesnt say it.

Comment: @HIH that is the disjoint union.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @HIH To be a bit more precise, $\sqcup$ is the disjoint union... *equipped with the disjoint union topology* a.k.a the coproduct (of $X$ and $D^n$). It's not always true that if $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint subsets then $A\cup B$ (which is a disjoint union) has the same topology as $A\sqcup B$

Comment: @FShrike May I ask how do open sets in disjoint union topology look like intuitively? Are they pairs of open sets from X and D^n? Also, does $X\sqcup D^n/\sim $ mean "treat X and D^n as "disjoint", then collect the equivalence classes, if $y\in X$ is not $f(x)$ for any x in D^n, then [y] is just {y}, if $y=f(x)$ for some x in D^n, then [y] can be understood as {f(x)} on X, so $X\sqcup D^n/\sim $ is drawing the boundary of D^n on X?

Comment: @HIH There are some latex errors. But take two spaces $A$ and $B$. $A\sqcup B$ is the space with underlying set $A\sqcup B$ (**note**: even if $A\cap B$ is nonempty, we still form this artificial "disjoint union" of (copies of) $A$ and $B$) and subsets of $A\sqcup B$ are open iff. their intersections with both $A$ and $B$ are open in $A,B$ resp. so... the open sets look like (disjoint) unions of open subsets of $A$ and $B$